# Repair/fix invalid HTML using Javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, html-parsing

I want to use content(some div) on the page.

So I request the the page using AJAX. Since I want to use some `div` (by `ID`), I have written  the following code but the problem is the HTML that gets returned from the `delete1.aspx` is faulty so I can not convert it to XML

```
 $('#one').click(function () {
     $.ajax({
         url: 'http://localhost:51967/delete1.aspx',
         success: function (data, status, xhr) {

             var temp = $.parseXML(data);
             $('#arjunvachhani').html($(temp).find('#id1').html());

         }
     });
 });
```

I have tried to put it on some hidden `div` so that browser will correct it and then retrieve that `div`, but in that case, the browser will request `css` and `js` and some other images which is changing appearance of my page(where I put the retrieved HTML). It is also very slow

One more problem "I can't change the delete1.aspx file"

Comment: Do you know what's wrong with the page, so you can use string replacement to repair it?

Comment: no i don't know what the problem. it has multiple problem such as image tags are not closed and much more. and i don't have control to change delete.aspx file

Comment: HTML doesn't require image tags to be closed. It sounds like it's valid HTML, but not valid XML.

Comment: This will remain a guessing game until we see the full code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's valid HTML, but not valid XML, try:

```
var temp = $('<div/>', { html: data });
$('#arjunvachhani').html(temp.find('#id1').html());
```

Comment: @RNKushwaha My assumption is that it's valid HTML, so no correction is necessary.